# Redirect a Google Docs form to your custom 'thank you' page

Tags: javascript, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Docs Form redirect after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077054/google-docs-form-redirect-after-submission)

Here's a Google form:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dE02TlBHQ2hnVVdkTE5ya0lBYXhaMlE6MQ&amp;ifq" method="POST" id="ss-form">
<br>
<div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text"><div class="ss-form-entry"><label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">First name
<span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span></label>
<label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_0"></label>
<input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0"></div></div></div>
<br> <div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text"><div class="ss-form-entry"><label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_1">Last name
<span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span></label>
<label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_1"></label>
<input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1"></div></div></div>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value="">
<div class="ss-item ss-navigate"><div class="ss-form-entry">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></div></div></form>
```

And here's the spreadsheet that it feeds:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApjOXzxlxbMhdE02TlBHQ2hnVVdkTE5ya0lBYXhaMlE

I wonder how to redirect the form to my own customized 'thank you' page on submission.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077054/google-docs-form-redirect-after-submission

Comment: Seems to be working, but there should be a more straightforward approach to such a simple problem.