# Custom Redirect after Submitting a Prefilled Google Form

Tags: html, google-forms

My question is basically a combination of these questions:

1. [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511)
2. [Google Docs Form redirect after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077054/1704355)

I successfully used [Sneaky Sheep Version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717481/1704355) to generate html for a custom thank-you page.

I was able to generate URLs to prefill form data using a script like [BuildBetterURLs() in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110656/1704355).

I'm new to html and I'm not sure if it's possible to use these two simultaneously so that whoever I send the prefilled form to gets my custom thank-you page once they submit the form.

Is it possible to redirect to a custom thank-you page with a prefilled Google Form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem.  I solved the pre-filled URL problem with simple string functions, so that my pre-filled URL is dynamic based on the latest responses.  I'm having a little bit of a struggle getting the pre-filled URL published in a dynamic manner, but my current solution is to publish the spreadsheet tab containing the URL (all other cells hidden), and sharing a link to this tab instead of directly to the form.  It's not an elegant solution, but it does get the user to the updated pre-filled link.

I think I'm hitting the same obstacle as you are.  Once they get to the thank-you page, there is no link back to the pre-filled form.  I have to force them back to the shared spreadsheet tab to get to the pre-filled URL again.  I don't have a solution to that part yet.